# Routing rules in web service

Tags: https, routes, rules

I have a configuration file.  It contains RouteRules and in this element, you add Rules within the Rules tag using the add.  Within the add element, it has a From parameter with a certificate line similar to the following:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <Rules>
    <add .... From="CN=*.domain.com, O=myorg, etc." />
  </Rules>
</RoutingRules
```

This is the line I think I can update to include https only, but I am not sure.

```
From="CN=*.domain.com, O=myorg, etc."
```

Can I configure this rule to only allow https?  I have seen posts that say in IIS you make it accept only https, but this does not seem to be what the customer wants.  They believe I can update the config file and enable only https traffic.